# JS generated not editable DIV can't focus (and blur) in Chrome till static HTML coded can

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, onblur

I found that in GoogleChrome (43.0.2357.132 m) a not editable JavaScript generated DIV can't get focus and so it never blur but static HTML coded DIV could.

Someone clould help me how to make the JS generated version to get focus and blur? (It works fine in IE)
Ther is some parameter that I don't set or something in Chrome?

I try to make my own combo box input by JS and i want use the not contenteditable divs like select options but i need to know if it blur to work it normally. So to set these to contenteditable not a solution...

Here the sample code to try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <!--HTML5-->
<html lang= "hu">
<head>  
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

        <script language = "javascript">
            function fblur(event){
            console.log('BLUR\nevent.target: '+event.target.id);
            console.log(event);
            alert('DIV BLUR EVENT FIRED');
            }

            function fclick(event){
            event.target.focus();
            console.log('CLICK\nevent.target: '+event.target.id);
            console.log(event);
            }
        </script>
    </head>  

    <body id="Body">
        <div style="border: 1px solid; 
             height: 20px; 
             width: 200px;"
             id="STATIC HTML DIV1" 
             contenteditable="false"
             tabindex="1"  
                 onclick="fclick(event)" 
                 onblur="fblur(event)" 
        >STATIC HTML DIV1</div>

        <BR />  

        <script language = "javascript">
            var uiobj=document.createElement("DIV");
            var t = document.createTextNode('JS GENERATED DIV1');
            document.body.appendChild(uiobj);
            uiobj.appendChild(t);
            uiobj.style.border = '1px solid';   
            //uiobj.style.display = 'block';    
            uiobj.style.height = '20px';    
            uiobj.style.width = '200px';
            uiobj.id = 'JS GENERATED DIV1'; 
            uiobj.contentEditable = false;
            uiobj.tabindex= '2';            
            uiobj.addEventListener('click', fclick, false);
            uiobj.addEventListener('blur', fblur, false);       
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you try it the first div will focused and blurred.
If blurred will alert it.
The second div should do the same and in ID it do it well, but in Chrome the second DIV won't blur.

Thanks the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To declare an element as focusable (and so as "blurable"), you need to set a `tabindex`. See:

> The tabindex content attribute allows authors to indicate that an
>   element is supposed to be focusable

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#focusable-area

Your problem is here:

```
uiobj.tabindex= '2';
```

It should be:

```
 uiobj.tabIndex= '2'; //with a capital I
```

So the difference between your two elements is not that one is dynamically generated, it's that one hasn't got a tabindex because of that typo. If you remove tabindex on your static one, it won't be focusable either.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really solve the problem. :)(I didint found it for weeks ago)